# Can't reference variables declared in setup()

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have recently tried to get into p5.js and on the first project I am working on I am experiencing a completely perverse issue that for whatever reason isn't mentioned anywhere else online from what I can find.

Any variable I define outside of setup() will be undefined, but that's a well known fact. The issue is that any variable I define inside of setup() will also be undefined, this means I can't use any variables at all.

Here is the code:

```
function setup() {
  const canvasRatio = 0.975;
  createCanvas(int(windowWidth*canvasRatio), int(windowHeight*canvasRatio));
  fill(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  var plyMov = createVector(0,0,0);
  var plyPos = createVector(0,0,0);
  const plySpd = 1;
  const plyEnable = 0;
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  drawPly();
}

function drawPly(){
  plyPos=createVector(plyPos.x+plyMov.x,plyPos.y+plyMov.y,0)
  plyMov=createVector(0,0,0);
  stroke(255,0,0);
  ellipse(int(width/2),int(height/2),80, 80);
}
```

Here is the traceback from chrome in vscode:

```
ReferenceError: plyPos is not defined
    at drawPly (https://magicgonads.github.io/p5test/sketch.js:18:23)
    at draw (https://magicgonads.github.io/p5test/sketch.js:14:3)
    at p5.redraw (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.js:16560:7)
    at p5.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.js:11593:12)
    at p5.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.js:11489:12)
    at new p5 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.js:11769:12)
    at _globalInit (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.8/p5.js:8048:7)
```

Comment: This is the basic way variables are scoped in almost any programmation languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any variable I define outside of setup() will be undefined, but that's a well known fact.

Umm, what? That is not a well-known fact. You might mean that you can't use Processing's functions before setup, but that doesn't stop you from defining a variable at the top of the sketch.

If you define a variable in `setup()`, it's only available in `setup()`. That's true of any variable defined inside any function.

If you want to use a variable in multiple functions, you should define it at the sketch level. You can still **initialize** it (give it a value) in the `setup()` function:

```
var plyPos;
var plyMov;

function setup() {
  const canvasRatio = 0.975;
  createCanvas(int(windowWidth*canvasRatio), int(windowHeight*canvasRatio));
  fill(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  plyMov = createVector(0,0,0);
  plyPos = createVector(0,0,0);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  drawPly();
}

function drawPly(){
  plyPos=createVector(plyPos.x+plyMov.x,plyPos.y+plyMov.y,0)
  plyMov=createVector(0,0,0);
  stroke(255,0,0);
  ellipse(int(width/2),int(height/2),80, 80);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I had to use processing's functions to define the variables so that explains why I can't use them before setup. However I remember reading another response that said that setup() effectively makes all the variables and a tutorial online that said that if a variable that doesn't exist yet anywhere else is defined in a function it becomes global.

Comment: It still seems to be undefined, somehow.

Comment: @MagicGonads It's hard to help you debug without seeing your code. You might consider posting an updated [mcve] in a new question.

Comment: It's the same code that is given in this answer. And same error message as in the original question

Comment: @MagicGonads Are you sure it's the exact same code? Are you maybe redefining a new variable with the same name inside the `setup()` function? Notice that I don't have `var` inside my `setup()` function.

Comment: It's the same code but I added the constants I was going to use later on in development (plySpd and plyEnable) and moved canvasRatio's definition to the top. These changes wouldn't do anything to the result as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What's worth noting is that now the red circle forms in the center, maybe the code does work and it's actually my debugging process that is incorrect. I'm using chrome to debug the script hosted on my github pages, through a vscode extension.

Comment: @MagicGonads Why do you expect the circle to move? You never set the `plyMov` vector to anything other than zero. Please try to be more specific: saying that your variable is undefined is a very specific error. It's a completely different thing if your code does not have any errors but just doesn't do what you expect. In that case you're usually making an implicit assumption that ends up being incorrect. :p

Comment: I don't expect it to move, I was saying that if the debug error was correct the red circle should have never appeared.

Comment: @MagicGonads I'm not sure what you mean. What exact error are you seeing? When I run the  code in my answer I don't get any errors. Are you sure it isn't an error message from before?

Comment: Ok now the debugger isn't throwing an error, it's certainly a flaw in my debugging process, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @MagicGonads I'm still not sure what you mean by "debugging process". What exactly are you doing? We can't see your screen, so you have to be very specific with your descriptions here. I can't recommend anything if I don't know what you're doing. What is a vscode extension? Can't you just use the debugger that comes with your browser? Why do you need to use a debugger on the code in my answer at all?

Comment: I am using the chrome debugger through Visual Studio Code.
That debugger was giving false issues with your code, now it has stopped for some reason.

Comment: @MagicGonads Sounds like an issue with visual studio, not with Processing or the code. You probably want to get that figured out before it sends you chasing other bugs that don't exist in the future.